# if $f^{\prime\prime}$ is bounded then $f^\prime$ is bounded by half of the constant?

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
f is differentiable in $[0,1], f(0)=f(1)=0, \forall x\in (0,1):|f''(x)|\le A $. 
Prove that $\forall x \in [0,1] : |f'(x)| \le \frac A2$

**My thought:**

I saw this theorem about uniformly continuous function in an open interval being bounded.
I think from $f''$ being bounded I can say that $f'$ is uniformly continuous on the open interval $(0,1)$ and therefore bounded. My two problems: What about the points $0,1$ which I also need to prove this statement is true for? and also - How can I prove the function is bounded by exactly $\frac A2$?

Thanks

Comment: It should be that $f$ is twice differentiable? And are you missing an $x$ for $x \in (0,1)$?

Comment: I think the given details imply that f is twice differentiable. About your second question, I don't understand it.

Comment: typo fixed now.

Comment: The first question was directed more towards why the statement "f is differentiable" is present, since that suggests that it might not be twice differentiable. If that fact is to be assumed from context (in particular that the 2nd derivative must exist everywhere), then that initial condition is pointless.

Comment: can anyone post an answer (or hints) on doing this question without using integrals?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is $s \in (0,1)$ with $f'(s) > A/2$ and $f(s) \ge 0$.  Then for
$t \in [s,1]$, $f'(t) = f'(s) + \int_s^t f''(x)\ dx > A/2 - A(t-s)$,
and $$f(1) = f(s) + \int_s^1 f'(x)\ dx > \int_s^1 (A/2 - A(x-s))\ dx = 
A s (1-s)/2 > 0$$
which is impossible.  Similarly in three other cases (in two of them you consider $f(0)$ rather than $f(1)$).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution, we haven't learned integrals yet.